# How to ignore collisions of triggers after first collision of trigger until OnTriggerExit of first collision of trigger?

Tags: unity, c#, ai, collider

There is are white and red two teams of tank which are auto spawning in certain time interval. both red and white type of tanks have triggers so when red and white tank come close enough, OntriggerEnter() is activated and both types of tank stop moving and start to fire each other. their movement is controlled by navemesh and both type of tanks are navmeshagent. Now What i want is when these two start firing each other both tank's trigger need to ignore collision of trigger with third tank until one of those two tanks die.
Below is my code any help is appreciated thanks.

```
      public float RBdist;
      public GameObject Rbullet;
      public Transform targetofred;
      public float attackspeedofRtank;
 private void Start()
{
   // rwalktohit = GetComponent<Animator>();
     red = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    //cube2.velocity = 2f * (cube2.velocity.normalized);
    red.destination = targetofred.position;
//targetofred is the position of house of white tank or base of white tank.

    Rcollider = GetComponent<Collider>();     
}
      private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider whitettank)
      {

          if (whitettank.gameObject.tag == "whitetank")//tag of white
// tanks is "whitetank".

        {
          red.isStopped = true;
          twhitetank = whitettank.transform;
          transform.LookAt(twhitetank.position);           
          InvokeRepeating("Rfire", 1f, attackspeedofRtank);
         }

      }

private void Rfire()
{

     GameObject Rbulletclone = Instantiate(Rbullet, transform.position , 
    transform.rotation);
     Rbulletclone.transform.position = 
   Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position , twhitetank.position, RBdist); 
}




private void OnTriggerExit(Collider whitettank)
{
    if (whitettank.gameObject.tag == "whitetank")
    {
        CancelInvoke("Rfire");
        red.isStopped = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `whitettank.CompareTag("whitetank")` instead of `whitettank.gameObject.tag == "whitetank"`. It's more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be as easy as:

```
if (whitettank.gameObject.tag == "whitetank" && !red.isStopped)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This way the script will skip over your shooting-code after the first time. When you want to re-enable it just set `red.isStopped` to `false` again.

Comment: to elaborate on this, essentially you're not disabling the trigger, just ignoring that something else has entered the area when the tank is already fighting.